# Macbook pro stuck on boot - "AppleUSBHostPort::interruptOccurred: overcurrent detected"

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, startup

I am trying to reinstall OSX on a MacBook Pro Mid-2009 but it hangs on startup.
I have used several disks but now when running in verbose mode see that it hangs at 
`"AppleUSBHostPort::interruptOccurred: overcurrent detected"`
and loops here.

Image of messages during startup:

[image]

Comment: Did you by any chance open up the MBP, f.e. to change the HD or SSD? "Overcurrent" points to a short in the electric connections cased by faulty wires or connections.

Comment: Only after the issue started - though very possible it could be cause by other "rough" behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You have a hardware problem with your USB ports and it's physical. It try to disable de USB ports but they can't so they throw this error.

It's hardware related, you can do nothing about.

Comment: Technically it is not just the (external) USB-Port but all devices connected to the MBP, f.e. the integrated Facetime Camera.

Answer (score 1):

When my MacBook Air dropped to the ground while a USB micro thumb drive was connected, the right-hand side USB connector got damaged. The port stopped working and since then it apparently has a minor short-circuit. In effect the area close to it gets warm and the laptop battery is drained within an hour. A hardware repair would likely require replacing the main logic board since unfortunately this USB connector is part of that board. A replacement part would cost US$ 300 and some 2 hours work for an experienced HW gugy, so I decided that this is not worth it for me.

I did not encounter any software issues until I upgraded my system from Mac OS X 10.8.6 Mountain Lion to 10.12.6 Sierra. Later I learned that [with 10.11 El Capitan the way USB ports are included has changed](https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/306777-guide-usb-fix-el-capitan-1011/).

When the system (any Mac OS X 10.11 or later) boots up it takes 2-3 times longer than usual while constantly emitting `dmesg` messages like the following:

```
XHC1@14000000: AppleUSBXHCI::hardwareException: kUSBCommandReset did not clear
XHC1@14000000: AppleUSBHostController::setPowerStateGated: going to state 2 failed with 0xe00002e9
```

After the fix mentioned below it still occasionally gives the following message, which is bearable and a good indication of the root cause:

```
AppleUSBHostPort::interruptOccurred: overcurrent detected with port status 0x4000, localSimulatedInterrupts = 0x0
```

Since then I've been struggling to find a way of disabling that USB port in a way that system boot is not held up and that the other, left-hand side USB port is still usable (at least in USB 2.0 High Speed mode). Finally I succeeded, and I'm sharing my solution here for others who might face a similar problem:

```
cd /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBHostFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns
```

Edit `AppleUSBEHCIPCI.kext/Contents/Info.plist` to remove or comment out (using XML comment start `<!--` and end `-->`) the entry for `AppleUSBXHCIPPT`:

```
            <!--<key>AppleUSBXHCIPPT</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
                    <string>com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI</string>
                    <key>IOClass</key>
                    <string>AppleUSBXHCIPPT</string>
                    <key>IOPCIPauseCompatible</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>IOPCIPrimaryMatch</key>
                    <string>0x1e318086</string>
                    <key>IOPCITunnelCompatible</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>IOProbeScore</key>
                    <integer>1000</integer>
                    <key>IOProviderClass</key>
                    <string>IOPCIDevice</string>
            </dict>-->
```

Alternatively, and more simply, disable `AppleUSBXHCIPCI` altogether:

```
sudo mv AppleUSBXHCIPCI.kext{,.disabled}
```

In both cases, finally

```
sudo touch /System/Library/Extensions && sudo kextcache -u /
```

and reboot.

Note that disabling the driver on-the-fly:

```
kextunload -b com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI
```

does not work because it is in use by some other kernel extension.