# Disable one USB port through kext editing on Macbook Pro running Monterey

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, battery, kernel-extensions

I have a battery drain problem on my MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports with Touchbar). It wakes up every minute during sleep with the following reason (from pmset -g log ) and goes back to sleep only for a few seconds.  My battery drains in about 6 hours repeating this.
Assertions            PID 99(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd000085a8 [System: DeclUser kDisp]
DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.DarkPME/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:85%) 14 secs

One of my Type C USB ports is broken and my current assumption is that this broken USB port is causing the battery drain issue.  I have read many many posts of users with similar battery drain problems and have come to this conclusion after trying out the many solutions (resets, disabling, disconnecting, clean install etc)  without success.
Although I understand a hardware fix is probably my best bet,  I feel it is not worth paying for a logic board replacement  and I would like to try disabling this port through software configuration changes.

The closest hint I found on how to do this is [this stackexchange post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215196/macbook-pro-stuck-on-boot-appleusbhostportinterruptoccurred-overcurrent-de?newreg=a87f4a7d7e1246d6a977e947d853eed9)
According to the last response to this post, it is possible to disable a certain USB port by editing
/System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBHostFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBEHCIPCI.kext/Contents/Info.plist

The post is old and the plist does not match what I see in my installation of Monterey version 12.5.1. All instructions relating to this kext seems to be for the purpose of USB port mapping hackintosh PCs. I can't find any info on how to configure real Macs or if it is even possible on Monterey.

My USB ports are below with the green items the ports used when USB2 and USB3 devices are connected to the 3 working ports. I would like to disable the broken ports but I don't see any mention of XHC1 or HS03 or SSP2 etc in my info.plist.
[image]

I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: The USB-C Ports on this model are modular (left side on one board, right side on one board, connected to the logic board by cable), so depending on what is actually defective it might be sufficient to replace just the ports. For troubleshooting you might want to consider disconnecting the ports on the problematic side temporarily to see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize the USB ports were modular. I will check how much it is to replace the ports or maybe disconnecting or replacing them myself.